# VLC media keys and stopping and starting second by second

Tags: vlc-media-player, fast-forward

I am doing dictation for short videos with VLC and need to rewind and fast-forward at second-only increments. For example, I listen to three seconds, need to listen again, and then rewind by second increments... I would go from 10:34 back to 10:32 for example.Then FF to 10:35. How do I get VLC to allow me to do second-incremental FF and Rewind?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 11):

VLC does have defaults for incremental jumps.  Before dealing with the specific length of time for each...

very short jump back/forward `shift+left/shift+right`

short jump back/forward `alt+left/alt+right`

medium jump back/forward `ctrl+left/ctrl+right`

long jump back/forward `ctrl+alt+left/ctrl+alt+right`

Now, if you go to the Preferences, and change from simple to All, expand the Interface option, and go to the Hotkey Settings section, you will see there below the window of hotkey choices where you can define the length of time for each of those jumps.  So, you can set the Very Short Jump to be just one second, and the Short Jump to 3 seconds... to speed up both of your movements.

[image: VLC Settings]

See?

Comment: @Jones or was this not what you actually meant?